# Event Handling in a Given Order

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

**Background info**: In Excel, when you perform cut on a selection of block, the values are not moved until you paste. After cut, if any event (not all but most) other than paste happens, the block is *not* moved.

I am trying to implement the same idea. I have 2 functions:

```
void MyFrame::OnCut(wxCommandEvent& evt);
void MyFrame::OnPaste(wxCommandEvent& evt);
```

Also following events are defined:

```
wxDEFINE_EVENT(CUT_EVENT, wxCommandEvent);
wxDEFINE_EVENT(PASTE_EVENT, wxCommandEvent);
```

The code in **OnCut** is structured in 2 blocks. 1st block should be performed when cut is called, 2nd block should be performed when Paste is called.

```
void MyFrame::OnCut(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    if (evt.GetEventType() != PASTE_EVENT){

         m_CutEventCalled = true;
         //Some code here

    }

     if (evt.GetEventType() == PASTE_EVENT)

        //Some code here
        m_CutEventCalled = false;

    }

}


void MyFrame::OnPaste(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    //Some other code 
    if(m_CutEventCalled){
        wxCommandEvent PasteEvent;
        PasteEvent.SetEventType(PASTE_EVENT);
        PasteEvent.SetEventObject(this);
        Bind(PASTE_EVENT, &MyFrame::OnCut, this);
        wxPostEvent(this, PasteEvent);
    }
}
```

The cut and paste events can be triggered by keyboard such as Ctrl+X, by ContextMenu or from RibbonButtons.

This, so far, works well if Cut event is *immediately* followed by a paste event. However, I want `m_CutEventCalled=false` when some other event happens between cut and paste, say user changed his/her mind and without pasting after cut instead triggered a copy event.

```
bool MyFrame::ProcessEvent(wxEvent & evt)
{
    static wxEvent* s_lastEvent = NULL;

    if (&evt == s_lastEvent)
        return false;

    int evtID = evt.GetId();

    //if this part of the code exists the whole thing doesnt work
    //otherwise it only works cut immediately followed by paste
    if (evtID != ID_PASTE && evtID != ID_CUT)
        m_CutEventCalled = false;


    return wxMDIChildFrame::ProcessEvent(evt);
}
```

My idea was any event with IDs other than ID_PASTE and ID_CUT should reset the `m_CutEventCalled=false`. However, so far no success. I assume it has something to do with `ProcessEvent`.

In other words, how can I know that `any` event other than paste event happened after the cut event. One solution would be that I can place `m_CutEventCalled=false` in all other event handlers but that does not seem to be an elegant solution.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: `evtID != ID_PASTE || evtID != ID_CUT` - this always evaluates to true

Comment: You are indeed right :) changed it, still the problem exists though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very strange approach to solving the problem. You absolutely don't need to interfere with the event handling because it doesn't matter at all whether the "paste" event immediately follows "cut" or not (in fact, spoiler: it never will, there will always be some intermediate events between any such events generated by the user).

You just need to remember the "cut" data in your `OnCut()` and then copy and remove it, if copied successfully, in your `OnPaste()`.

Comment: The problem is I have many other events such as OnCopy... Where I am having the confusion is if the events say are in the following order: 1) OnCut 2) OnCopy (can be some other event) 3) OnPaste, if this sequence happens I dont want to move the block. I only want to move the data if 1) OnCut 2) OnPaste sequence happens, which works well. Now how can I know whether OnCopy or other event happened in between #1 and #3.

Comment: You need to update your internal state to reflect `OnCopy()` call. I.e. you presumably have some internal clipboard containing the data that was cut or copied and a boolean flag indicating whether it was the latter or the former. `OnCopy()` should just update this flag and then `OnPaste()` would know better than to delete the original data.

Comment: I thought about that but to me that approach will work if the sequence is 1)OnCut 2)OnCopy 3)OnPaste. However, for example if the sequence is 1)OnCut 2)DataGridCellEdited (or some other event) 3)OnPaste then it will not work, since  the data should not be moved in the latter sequence either. What I have later on done is to use the `evt.SetString` of `wxCommandEvent` and then collect related events in `std::vector<wxEvent*>`. At OnPaste I check the `std::vector<wxEvent*>` to see if the recent event was `OnCut`. So far this approach works well but not sure if I will hit some dead-end somewhere.

Comment: Editing the previously cut data should invalidate your internal clipboard contents.

Comment: Indeed so; however, say OnCut cuts "A1:B5" and user started to edit "C10" immediately after cut. Then the data of "A1:B5" should not be moved, if user clicks paste after editing "C10".  MS Excel handles this in a very neat way by not only not moving the data but also by removing the copied data from the clipboard as well. Libre and OpenOffice immediately removes the data on an OnCut event but relies on Undo/Redo to retrieve it back. I might choose the latter approach as it seems to require much less code and seems less complicated to implement.